# How to allow all and any requests with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've just added Spring Security to my project. I've also added this configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

}
```

but now not all of my endpoints work. In fact only a single endpoint works, for the rest I get `403 Forbidden`. What could be the problem? How can I allow **any and all** requests (effectively making security a pass-through).

Comment: try this `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll().anyRequest()`

Comment: Is the working end point perhaps a GET request, and all the failing ones POST requests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to allow some URL to be accessed without authentication, it is a better practice to prepare some whitelist and pass it to the method `antMatchers()`.

The `antMathers()` accepts *wild cards* as well. If you surely don't want any of the endpoints to be authenticated put `/**`. But you already have Spring Security, why not use the full power of it.

Here is a simple way of doing it.

```
private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
   "/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources/**",
};

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/csrf").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated(); 
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I had to add `.csrf().disable()` to make it work.

So the whole solution for me was

```
http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
```

Comment: Okay. According to the documentation `csrf()` "Enables CSRF protection. This is activated by default when using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter's default constructor." So `csrf().disable()` actually disables protection and permits CSRF.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
```

Comment: Why? What is different between this and their attempt?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking. Who's "they"?

Comment: I think they were referring to the FAQ: if there is already an answer to a question improve that, and don't post your own.

Comment: Oh, but when I posted this there were no answers yet.

Comment: They = the OP. What does `antMatchers("/**")` do differently than `anyRequest()`?